# How to Limit Bootstrap Column Width on Large Devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following divs that use Bootstrap 3.0 CSS:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

While this looks and behaves the way I want on XS to medium-sized devices, the expanded columns on large devices (>1200px) ruin my design.

**Is there a way to stop bootstrap from expanding column width to 95px on large devices?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Limiting the container width to max container width for medium devices (970px) will do the trick:

```html
<div class="container" style="max-width: 970px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to limit only one column? i.e. if i want side menu to be fixed width...

Comment: @Astellar You can set the side menu to fixed/max width and set the main column to have the class `col`, which will fill the rest of the space

Comment: If you want to do only one column I'd create another `<div>` inside of a column and set max-width on that element. That way, you maintain the rest of the behavior.

Comment: I had the same problem as Eugene and I fixed it with what @LukaKerr suggested. More specific, I had a row with three columns (vertical nav bar, collapsable side bar, and a main panel). The vertical nav bar got a fixed width without a "col" class. The (via Bootstrap 5) collapsable side bar had a "col-2" class. The main pal got a simple "col" without additions, so it was able to take up the full remaining space and adapt to changes of the viewport and when the collapsable side bar was toggled.